# HIVE check for data from table 1 which is absent in table 2

Tags: sql, hive

I am looking to create a HIVE SQL query to find all the values from table 1 which ARE NOT present in table 2. I understand that I need to use a join however I cannot figure out how to implement it for this situation...

Thanks,
James

for example:

```
Table1

url                  number
xe.com               5
google.com           2
ebay.co.uk           6

Table2

url                  visits
facebook.com         8
google.com           4
ebay.co.uk           15
```

So for example the query should return all values from Table1 which are present in Table2, i.e.

```
url                  number         visits
google.com           2              4
ebay.co.uk           6              15
```

Comment: You're going to have to include more information if you want a suitable answer. The schema of the tables and how they link together would be a good start.

Comment: Sorry I assumed the question was simple enough that it didn't require any information about the data schema. I have edited the post and included the information :)

Comment: Basically I'm looking for a way to do an anti join...

Comment: Your example is a simple join on url

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A LEFT JOIN will return all rows from `Table1` regardless of whether or not there's a match. In the case that there isn't a match the columns from `Table2` will have the value `NULL` - these are the rows you want:

```
SELECT Table1.url, Table1.number
FROM Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.url = Table2.url
WHERE Table2.url IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but should this not be: SELECT Table1.url, Table1.number FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.url = Table2.url
WHERE Table2.url IS NULL

Comment: @user2160581 Yep, got ahead of myself and missed the `FROM` line when typing it up; fixed now.

Comment: and for the purposes of HIVE which I am using it should be LEFT OUTER JOIN. THANKS :)